# Any way to optimize large input's memory usage in keras?

Tags: python, memory, neural-network, out-of-memory, keras

I am trying to use 2D CNN to do text classification on Chinese articles and have some trouble of keras `Convolution2D`. I know the basic flow of `Convolution2D` to cope with image, but stuck by using my dataset with keras. This is one of my problems:

### Dataset

1. 9800 Chinese Article.

   negative article and non-negtive article[please note it may be positive or neutrality] , just a binary classification problem. I have a test on `Convolution1D` NN, but the result is not good.
2. Use tokenizer and word2vec to transform to a shape `(9800, 6810, 200)`.

   longest article has 6810 word, shortest article has less 50 word， need padding all article to 6810， 200 is word2vec size(Seems some people call it embedding_size ? ). Format like:

   ```
    1     [[word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200]]
    2     [[word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200]]
    ....
    9999  [[word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200], [word2vec size=200]]
   ```

Is the article max. word length 6810 too large? 
I have to reduce the 9800 samples to 6500 to avoid a `MemoryError`, because 6500 already eats all my 32GB RAM. Any way to optimize the memory usage except trimming all the articles to a shorter length?

Answer (score 5):

The [Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-use-keras-with-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory) already answers this question partly. You can load your data in chunks using [`model.fit_generator()`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator). The generator runs in a separate thread and produces your mini-batches, possibly loading them from your archive one-by-one, avoiding loading everything into RAM at once.

The code for using this would roughly look like this:

```
def train_generator():
    while True:
        chunk = read_next_chunk_of_data()
        x,y = extract_training_data_from_chunk(chunk)
        yield (x,y)

 model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator())
```

Comment: Note that for multi-input (output) models, X (y) is a list of numpy arrays.